# Could not create servlet in web application project (google app engine) by using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am following Google App Engine Guestbook sample to create a new servlet in src folder. When the create servlet dialog open, I found I can't choose or type "Web Project" and can't browse to select "source folder" either.

The eclipse is version 3.5, jdk I installed is 1.6.0_14-b08

I am working on Windows XP Pro with SP3.

Before I tried to create new servlet, I can compile and start the server, after visiting http://localhost:8080, sample app works fine.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This happens if none of your projects were created as "Dynamic Web Project". For example if you did :

> `New --> Maven Project --> maven-archetype-webapp --> etc.`

To correct this either create a project via:

> `New --> Dynamic Web Project`

or right-click your existing project and do:

> `Properties --> Project Facets --> Convert to facet form...`

Tick`Dynamic Web Module`(verifying the version) then click`OK`

Comment: Just be aware that once you add this facet, there is no going back and it will alter the organization within your project explorer, but not the file system.

Answer (score 2):

Same here. In the Create Servlet dialog (opened by right clicking on the package in my project, New > Other, then choose Web > Servlet), there is no choice in the "Project" drop down list:
[image]

The "Browse" buttons for Source folder and Java package doesn't work either.

Installing GWT Web Project and adding such support in the existing project don't help. BTW, the project is already a Web Application Project created following the instructions stated here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating.html

Instead, I have to create a Class and then manually set the superclass as javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet to add a servlet to the project.

Is it a bug in Google Plugin or Eclipse?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Seems like it should be easier than creating it in a text editor and copying it into the folder every time.

Answer (score 1):

That may be because you did not installed the [GWT (Google Web Toolkit) eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html) first.

[alt text http://download.instantiations.com/DesignerDoc/integration/latest/docs/html/gwt/images/web-new-project1.gif](http://download.instantiations.com/DesignerDoc/integration/latest/docs/html/gwt/images/web-new-project1.gif)

See also this [GWT Web Project guide](http://download.instantiations.com/DesignerDoc/integration/latest/docs/html/gwt/web_project_creation.html).

Comment: Von, thanks for the reply, I did installed the GWT and AppEngine eclipse plugin. The project I created for that guestbook sample is a Web Application Project from Google folder. Also in the guestbook sample doc, it mentioned uncheck the GWT option. It supposed to be separated from GWT, right?

Answer (score 0):

solution to this problem is very simple, create a simple servlet file in notepad and copy that file into your projects package folder, and then start editing the file in eclipse.

Comment: Don't forget to add it to your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be an old known missing feature/bug.. [Gae issue link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2306#c1)
From my experience today (06-2014), it has still not been dealt with yet.

> Reported by Lars.Vo...@gmail.com, Oct 22, 2009
>
> Eclipse provides a wizard to create new servlets. This wizard allows
>   to create servlets for dynamic web projects only.
>
> The projects created the the Google Plugin do not have the right
>   nature, so you cannot use the wizard to create servlets.
>
> Can you please fix this?
>
> Example:
>
> - Create a new "Web Application Project". Select File -> New -> Other -> Servlet
> - Look at the wizard